# How to make a function inside a class mutuable?

Tags: java

Imagine I have a class

```
class A {
 int a;
 int b;

 A(int a, int b) {
  this.a=a; this.b=b;
 }

 int theFunction() {
   return 0;
 }

 void setTheFunction([...]) {
    [...]
 }
}
```

And for every new object I instantiate, I want to be able to define `theFunction()` in a new way by calling `setTheFunction( [...] )`. For example, I want to do something like this:

```
A test = new A(3,2);
test.setTheFunction ( int x = a*b; return x*x+2; );
System.out.println(test.theFunction()); // Should return (3*2)*(3*2)+2 = 38
```

Or something like this:

```
A test2 = new A(1,5);
test.setTheFunction ( for(int i=0; i<b; i++) a=a*b*i; return a; );
```

Now, what I could of course do is write all of those functions inside class A and use a switch statement to determine which one is to pick. But if I don't want the algorithm of `theFunction()` hardcoded inside my class A, is there any way to do something similar to the above? And what would `setTheFunction()` look like? What type of argument would you have to pass?

Comment: Injecting java code dynamically like you are doing in your examples is not possible in Java, as it is not a functional language.

Comment: Use the strategy design pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).

```
public class A<V> {

    public int a;
    public int b;
    private Callable<V> callable;

    public A(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public V theFunction() {
        try {
            return callable.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setTheFunction(Callable<V> callable) {
        this.callable = callable;
    }
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
final A<Integer> test = new A<Integer>(3, 2);
test.setTheFunction(new Callable<Integer>() {
    int x = test.a * test.b;
    return x * x + 2;
});
System.out.println(test.theFunction());
```

Of course, the generic typing of `A` isn't necessary, but I've added it to make this answer to be less restricted.

Comment: While this is what OP wants using behavior design pattern (with some more abstraction) would be nicer, imo.

Answer (score 4):

If you always need to operate on the same arguments, you could solve this by defining an interface such as:

```
public interface MethodPerformer {    
  int performOperation(int a, int b);
}
```

Then pass in implementations of this to your `setTheFunction` method. Finally, invoke the operation when you call the other method:

```
class A {
 int a;
 int b;
 MethodPerformer performer;

 A(int a, int b) {
  this.a=a; this.b=b;
 }

 int theFunction() {
   performer.performOperation(a, b);
 }

 void setTheFunction(MethodPerformer performer) {
    this.performer = performer;
 }
}
```

Clearly additional code would be required to check the performer is not `null`. Perhaps take a performer in the constructor?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a setter, the more natural way is to use an anonymous sub-class.  This way the compiler will check it behaves correctly and has access to the right variables.

```
public class Main {
    static abstract class A {
        protected int a, b;

        A(int a, int b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        public abstract int theFunction();
    }

    public static void main(String... ignored) {
        A test = new A(3, 2) {
            @Override
            public int theFunction() {
                int x = a * b;
                return x * x + 2;
            }
        };

        System.out.println(test.theFunction()); // Should return (3*2)*(3*2)+2 = 38

        A test2 = new A(1, 5) {
            @Override
            public int theFunction() {
                for (int i = 1; i < b; i++) a = a * b * i;
                return a;
            }
        };
        System.out.println(test2.theFunction());
    }
}
```

prints

```
38
15000
```

Comment: I like this answer's approach; the variable access in my answer is definitely unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

With this you can solve any kind of problem, that involves any kind of public variable of `A` (but can work with package private variables as well, if the `AFunction` implementation resides in the same package), that a function may use to perform it's operation. It's just not as compact as it can be in other languages than java.

```
interface AFunction
{
    int call(A a);
}
class A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    //giving it a default implementation
    private AFunction f = new AFunction()
    {
        @Override
        public int call(A a)
        {
            return a.a * a.b;
        }
    };
    A(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    int theFunction()
    {
        return f.call(this);
    }
    void setTheFunction(AFunction f)
    {
        this.f = f;
    }
}
```

By the way as AlexTheo points out, all answers so far (except for Peter Lawrey's) are a form of the strategy design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is defining "A" as an interface instead of a class. You declare theFunction() without actually implementing it.
In client code, everytime you need "A", you instantiate a so-called anonymous inner class.
For example:

```
new A() { @Override public int theFunction() { ...your implementation... } };
```

Comment: adding an interface to the mix will make the implementation more complicated, but your answer goes the way that Peter Lawrey's goes.